# TcpMessageMapper - Null payload from connection x.x.x.x:xxxx:0e07144c-456e-4e31-a93c-66926b8f7018 while using FailoverClientConnectionFactory

Tags: spring-integration

I am having an issue if server getting switched between A to B. If A is down and B is up. Using FailoverClientConnectionFactory and I can see below warning while sending any request to server.

WARN  o.s.i.i.t.c.TcpMessageMapper - Null payload from connection cisco-x.x.x.x:42017:58773:0e07144c-456e-4e31-a93c-66926b8f7018

I am using FailoverClientConnectionFactory with like two of the servers. its working if fist server is up and running. But not working if its getting switched to B server.

Here is the code snippet:

```
@Bean
    public FailoverClientConnectionFactory getFailoverClientConnectionFactory() throws CiscoConnectionFailureException 
    {
        FailoverClientConnectionFactory failoverCF = new FailoverClientConnectionFactory(underlyingCF());
        failoverCF.setSingleUse(false);
        failoverCF.afterPropertiesSet();

        return failoverCF;
    }

@Bean
    public List<AbstractClientConnectionFactory> underlyingCF() throws CiscoConnectionFailureException 
    {

            List<ServerInfo> processServers = mConfigurationService.getProcesservers();
            List<AbstractClientConnectionFactory> factories = new ArrayList<>();
            boolean connectionSuccessful = false;
            for (ServerInfo serverInfo : processServers) 
            {
                AbstractClientConnectionFactory clientFactory = new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory(
                        serverInfo.getServerAddress(), serverInfo.getServerPort());
                clientFactory.setSingleUse(false);
                clientFactory.setDeserializer(mMessageSerializerDeserializer);
                clientFactory.setSerializer(mMessageSerializerDeserializer);                
                factories.add(clientFactory);

            }
            return factories;

    }

@Bean(name = "outAdapter.client")
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "input", requiresReply = "true")
    public TcpSendingMessageHandler getOutboundChannelAdapter(
            FailoverClientConnectionFactory failoverClientConnectionFactory)
    {
        TcpSendingMessageHandler outboundChannelAdapter = new TcpSendingMessageHandler();
        outboundChannelAdapter.setOrder(OUTBOUND_ADAPTOR_ORDER);
        outboundChannelAdapter.setConnectionFactory(failoverClientConnectionFactory);
        outboundChannelAdapter.setClientMode(true);

        return outboundChannelAdapter;
    }
```

Can anyone having an idea what is the issue?

Comment: You need to show your `mMessageSerializerDeserializer` code - that message means the deserializer returned `null` when `deserialize()` was called, which should never happen.

Comment: Thanks Gary. Null response was getting sent by server, so it seems desired behave.

Comment: But one more thing I am seeing, connection getting dropped with A server and B server is also not up. After some time A server getting up and connection getting successfully established with Server A. But still its trying to connect with B server, is this desired behavior?

Comment: 2020-02-25 21:5 .FailoverClientConnectionFactory$FailoverTcpConnection - Got Server A:42027:56894:284fd584-5401-41bb-81b6-c02c8e2080c0 from org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetClientConnectionFactory@2fc49538, host=Server A, port=42027
2020-02-25 21:50:16 [pool-6-thread-2] DEBUG o.s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetConnection - Server A:42027:56894:284fd584-5401-41bb-81b6-c02c8e2080c0 Reading...
2020-02-25 21:50:16DEBUG o.s.i.i.t.c.ClientModeConnectionManager - Connection 9b8633f1-cab3-4c0b-8735-02848c747160:1 established

Comment: 2020-02-25 21:50:36 [task-scheduler-6] DEBUG o.s.i.i.t.c.FailoverClientConnectionFactory$FailoverTcpConnection - org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetClientConnectionFactory@4001d8c1, host=Server B, port=42027 failed with java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect, trying another

Comment: It seems a bit odd that the "failover" server returns a different result to the other one. If both servers are down we keep trying both until one comes up. If B comes up before A, it is likely that you will connect there. We won't fail back to A until B goes down. Don't put stuff like that in comments, it's hard to read; edit the question instead.